# Bootstrap fixed bottom form-actions

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Twitter bootstrap fluid layout. On a page, I have a large form with at the bottom a `<div class="form-actions">` with a save button. I'd like to have this div to be visible all the time, so that the user doesn't always have to scroll down to the bottom of the page. I tried using this piece of CSS:

```
.fixed {position: fixed !important;}
```

It works when the table fits in the viewport, but mysteriously disappears when the table is too large. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting some values for either `top` or `bottom` depending on where you want it to be anchored.

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
 }
```